# The shortest way to assign variable boolean in JavaStript?

Tags: javascript, variables, code-snippets, assign

How can i write less code in this case ?

```
let a = true;
let b = false;
let c = false;

let R = false

if(a === true || b === true || c === true) {
    R = true
}
```

can i assign R with one line ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them into an array and use `.some`:

```
const R = [a, b, c].some(Boolean);
```

or, for the particular case of true and false mapping onto true and false:

```
const R = a || b || c;
```

Comment: The second is certainly shorter than the first :-)

Answer (score 1):

let a = true;

let b = c = R = false;

R = a || b || c;